# colocar a data no formato DD/MM/YYYY - js

Tags: javascript, data, timezone

Gente, estou com esse código abaixo mas não to conseguindo colocar no formato DD/MM/YYYY . Poderiam me ajudar?

```js
function run(dados) {
  /* dados = JSON.parse(dados);
  return dados[0].u_linhadigitavel;
*/
  var resp = JSON.parse(dados);
  var numero = "";
  var data_venc = "";
  var obj = {};

  size = Object.keys(resp).length;

let output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  let numero = `Código do boleto`;
  let data_venc = `Data de vencimento`;

  let linhaDigitavel = resp[i].u_linhadigitavel;

  let data = new Date(resp[i].u_datavencimento);
  let dataFormatada = data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", { timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo", day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'});
  

  output += `${numero}: ${linhaDigitavel}\n${data_venc}: ${dataFormatada}\n\n`;
}
return output;
```

**tentei dessa forma também**
function run(dados) {
/* dados = JSON.parse(dados);
return dados[0].u_linhadigitavel;
*/
var resp = JSON.parse(dados);
var numero = "";
var data_venc = "";
var obj = {};

size = Object.keys(resp).length;

let output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {

let numero = `Código do boleto`;
let data_venc = `Data de vencimento`;

let linhaDigitavel = resp[i].u_linhadigitavel;

let data = new Date(resp[i].u_datavencimento);
let dataFormatada = data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", { timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"});
let formata = dataFormatada.format('DD/MM/YYY')

output += `${numero}: ${linhaDigitavel}\n${data_venc}: ${formata}\n\n`;
}
return output;

Comment: `data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", { timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo" })` já faz o que vc precisa. O que mais falta?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, creio que fazer isso resolve:

```
  var data = new Date();
  var dia = String(data.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mes = String(data.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var ano = data.getFullYear();
  var dataAtual = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano;
```

Comment: oi, ale! 
mas assim estará em timezone?